# Compare two strings to a value in C#

Tags: c#, .net

```
        string 1= reportCard.1.GetText();
        string 2= reportCard.2.GetText();
        string 3= reportCard.3.GetText();
        string 4= reportCard.4.GetText();
        string 5= reportCard.5.GetText();
```

How do I write an if statement which check if any of the above values is false. I need to write an or operate and compare to a Y/N value

```
if ((1||2||3||4).Equals("No"))
```

This is giving error - "Cannot be applied to operands string"

Comment: You'd get a compile-time earlier than that - `1` isn't a valid identifier. I suspect you've already got code that *does* compile so far, so please present *that* rather than invalid pseudo-code.

Comment: That won't compile. Names of things in c# cannot start with a number

Comment: This is a fine example of a case where you should use a collection like an array or list to have your data in; it allows you to support a variable number of things without having to recompile your program. If your report cards were in an array you could write `reportCards.Any(rc => rc.GetText() == "false")` or, if you haven't been taught LINQ yet, something like `bool foundAFalse = false; foreach(ReportCard rc in reportCards) if(rc.GetText() == "false") { foundAFalse = true; break; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise against using `==` to test string equality. Use `String.Equals()` instead.

You can also do this in one statement using Linq:

```
if ((new [] {string1, string2, ...}).Any(s=>string.equals(s,"No",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
 DoStuff();
}
```

This will `DoStuff()` if any of your strings are equal to "no" ignoring the case.

See [String.Equals()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netcore-3.1) and [Enumerable.Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1) for further reading. It should be noted that an `Enumerable` is any class that can be enumerated, so this includes almost all collections like arrays and lists.

Replace `string1,string2,...` with all of your string variable names. I'd also advise changing your report card class to have a `List<string>` of results (assuming all of your results are strings) rather than these fields. That way you could enumerate over it like a collection.

See [List<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1).

You also can't have variable names that start with strings.

---

If you absolutely HAVE to use ORs, you need to perform each comparison separately and then chain them together. The way you've done it essentially reads "if string1 or string2 or string3 or string4 equals "no"". Which will evaluate as though you're saying ((string1 or string2) or (string3 or string4)) equals "no".

Obviously, "apple or pair" isn't a valid operation. So what you want is "string1 equals "no" or string2 equals "no" or string3 equals "no"...

To do this in C# you'd use something like:

```
if (string1 == "No" ||
    string2 == "No" ||
    stringN == "No" ||)
{
   DoStuff();
}
```

I'd strongly advise against using this approach though as it's poor practice. Even if it's beyond the scope of your assignment, read up on the links I've posted and try and implement it in a more robust fashion. If this is a school assignment, most teachers will be happy to see a "better" solution than the one they're looking for. Just don't copy and paste the code I've provided and make sure you understand it.

Comment: I agree with what you've said, but look at the wording of the question like "I have to use an OR and.." and the evidence pointing to the level of proficiency in c# the OP has attained; this is quite likely a programming 101 homework and you've just given an answer using collection initializers, linq, culture based string comparison. I'd bet money these haven't been taught yet, so it's not really doing the OP any favors

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @CaiusJard I've added an edit to address this. Programming 101 or not, it's never too early for people to do their own research and provide good solutions beyond what the instructor would expect.

Comment: You also make an unqualified recommendation to compare strings with Equals instead of == (where did the op use == ?); just wanted to note that this isn't java - for the most part it's not a problem to use == for c# string comparison. I'd be tempted to leave the finer points of reference comparison etc for another time :)

Comment: People keep telling me this, and tbh as a supervisor if someone who couldn't even write a compilable MCVE turned in anything with a lambda in it I'd know it was copied straight off the internet. Educate by all means, but education does *not* entail "giving them a fish", it entails "teaching them how to fish" and letting them turn in their own catches

Answer (score 0):

Should rather be like below .. you need to test for the values of each variable and compound their output.

Considering you have your variable defined like below

```
 string a = "No";
 string b = "No";
 string c = "No";
 string d = "No";
```

You can check

```
if ((a == "No" ||b == "No" ||c == "No" ||d == "No" )
```

You can as well use `All()` method from `System.Linq`

```
if((new[] {a,b,c,d}).All(x => x == "No"))
```

Comment: Your answer contains an unbalanced number of opening and closing parentheses

Comment: Didn't you mean `Any(x => x == "No")`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Your code has some issues:

1. You cannot name variables just with numbers in C#. You could name them like, v1, v2, v3 etc.
2. since you want to compare boolean values why you are using string variables? Instead, you could declare your variables as follows: `bool v1 = bool.Parse(reportCard.1.GetText());`. Here you have to make sure that the string values which come from the object (reportCard) are suitable to boolean values. such as"True" or "False".

Then you can simply write the if statement as follows:

```
if (!v1 || !v2 || !v3 || !v4):
{
   // do smth;
}
```